# Component disappears on update

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, mobx, mobx-react

I am implementing a word search facility in my React Native app. I have a MobX store, `wordStore`. Each text change triggers a database query via the `setFilter` action. This all works under the hood as I can see from console debug output.

However, the `WordList` component seems to disappear as soon as any updates are triggered, i.e. if I set a default filter string it shows matching items in the list, but as soon as any text changes it disappears.

Is there anything I'm missing? The strange thing is the `WordList.render()` method is executed even though it is not visible.

**EDIT:** Rendering the array's `.toString()` method works fine from the containing component, but strangely iterating over the array also displays the same behaviour, disappearing on update.

The containing component:

```
const WordSearch = observer(class WordSearch extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    render() {
      let words = wordStore.getWords(); // For debugging
      return (
        <View>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={(filter) => wordStore.setFilter (filter)}
            value={wordStore.filter}
          />
          <Text>{words.toString()}</Text> <!-- This works -->
          <View style={{flex:1}} key={wordStore.filter}> <!-- This disappears too -->
            {words.map((word, i) => {
            console.log ('word: '+word);
            return <View style={{flex:1}} key={i}>
              <Text>{word}</Text>
            </View>
            })}
          </View>
          <WordList {...this.props} />
        </View>
      );

    }
    // ...
});
```

and the WordList component:

```
const WordList = observer(class WordList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
    })
  }

  componentWillReact() {
    console.log("I will re-render, since the words have changed!");
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    console.log("Will update")

    let words = wordStore.getWords();
    this.dataSource = this.dataSource.cloneWithRows(words);
    console.log ("words:");
    console.log (words);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          key={wordStore.words}
          dataSource={this.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderWordRow}
          style={styles.listView}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

  renderWordRow = (word, sectionID, rowID) => {
    console.log ('rendering word row: '+word) 
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight 
          underlayColor="grey">
          <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{word}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );      
  }
});

export default WordList;
```

Comment: What does the console window look like after starting the app, then changing the filter? Have you verified that `getWords()` is working as it should?

Comment: @Glubus yes it all works as it should, console output shows the updated results, and also the output of `words.toString()` in the containing component is updated as expected

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a silly mistake. It was due to the `flex` not being set in the containing view. The correct code for the above example:

```
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        onChangeText={(filter) => wordStore.setFilter (filter)}
        value={wordStore.filter}
      />
      <WordList {...this.props} />
    </View>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar issue where a component wasn't being rendered because one of it's parents in the hierarchy didn't have a `flex: 1`.